# How to install qemu-kvm from source

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I previously installed kvm via apt-get.

Then I install qemu from source via following steps:

`wget http://wiki.qemu.org/download/qemu-2.1.91.tar.bz2`

`cd qemu-2.1.91`

`./configure`

`make && make install`

Then, when I type command `qemu-kvm`, I get the message:

`qemu-kvm: command not found`

What's more, `kvm --version` shows:

`QEMU emulator version 1.0 (qemu-kvm-1.0), Copyright (c) 2003-2008 Fabrice Bellard`

However, some tools version about qemu like `qemu-img`, `qemu-arm` and so on shows 2.1.91

`qemu-img version 2.1.91, Copyright (c) 2004-2008 Fabrice Bellard`

So, I wonder what I have missed. Any help would be appreciated.